# Multijob DSL - How to "label" each phaseJob with specific node/cloud/agent in Job DSL plugin?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to **label** each **phaseJob** in **multiJob** DSL plugin with specific node (in my case it's docker-cloud created with Docker Plugin).

Instead of labeling each **phaseJob** with specific node (docker-cloud) it labels every job with latest mentioned docker-cloud/node label.

I've tried the following example DSL configuration:

```
multiJob('example-multiple-job') {
    steps {
        phase('First') {
            phaseJob('JobA'){
                label('docker-a')
                shell('echo Hello World JobA!') 
                shell('sleep 1m')
            }
            phaseJob('JobB'){
                label('docker-b')
                shell('echo Hello World JobB!')
                shell('sleep 1m')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, it labels whole multiJob with **docker-b** label (as it is the latest one)

In addition to that, I've given a try to the following syntax:

```
multiJob('example-multiple-job') {
    steps {
        phase('First') {
            job('JobA'){
                label('main-docker-a')
                shell('echo Hello World JobA!') //
                shell('sleep 1m')
            }
            job('JobB'){
                label('main-docker-b')
                shell('echo Hello World JobB!')
                shell('sleep 1m')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It creates jobs with expected label, but they are not included in Multiple job project.

My expectentions are:

Each following **phaseJob** is runnign on it's own docker-cloud node and automatically included in Multiple job project automatically as it done without labeling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time reading Job DSL docs I came with solution. Actually, just had to read it more attentive :)

Here is working example of how several jobs with it's own labeled node/docker-cloud could be executed in parallel with, in docker containers

```
job('JobA') {
    label('docker-a')
    steps {
        shell('echo Hello World Job-A!')
        shell('sleep 1m')
    }
}

job('JobB') {
    label('docker-b')
    steps {
        shell('echo Hello World Job-B!')
        shell('sleep 1m')
    }
}

multiJob('example-multiple-job') {
    steps {
        phase('First') {
            phaseJob('JobA')
            phaseJob('JobB')
        }
    }
}
```

As I unserstood, jobs and everythign else is created separatly, but **multipleJob()** directive just helps to manage them all with additional behavior and features.